# Visual Studio 2013: Method not found: 'Void System.Diagnostics.Tracing.FrameworkEventSource.BeginG

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

when trying to bind solution from Source Control Explorer in VS2013,
getting the above message.

it appears Sytem.Diagnostics.Tracing does not have 
FrameworkEventSource class does it ?

this is for Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

.NET framework 4.6 did the trick here!!!  :)

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44928